# How to write a VBS file that download file to startup folder

Tags: vbscript

How can i write a vbs file that download file to startup folder, here is my code but i'm getting "ERROR: Target folder not found."

```
Sub HTTPDownload( myURL, myPath )
    Dim i, objFile, objFSO, objHTTP, strFile, strMsg
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    If objFSO.FolderExists( myPath ) Then
        strFile = objFSO.BuildPath( myPath, Mid( myURL, InStrRev( myURL, "/" ) + 1 ) )
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists( Left( myPath, InStrRev( myPath, "\" ) - 1 ) ) Then
        strFile = myPath
    Else
        WScript.Echo "ERROR: Target folder not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strFile, ForWriting, True )
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
    objHTTP.Send
    For i = 1 To LenB( objHTTP.ResponseBody )
        objFile.Write Chr( AscB( MidB( objHTTP.ResponseBody, i, 1 ) ) )
    Next
    objFile.Close( )
End Sub

      HTTPDownload "https://example.com/start.txt", "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start.txt"
```

Comment: What is C# or C++ about this?

Comment: Because people that have the knowledge of c# or c++ will have the knowledge of how to accomplish this.

Comment: That's not how tags work, don't do that with your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

`"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start.txt"` is not a valid path.

You have two options.

**1. Use a relative path.**

Start the script in e.g. your home directory and use `".\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start.txt"`

**2. Use an absolute path.**

Either manually hard-code the full target path into the script, or expand any environment variables before you use the path.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

path = "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start.txt"
finalPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(path)
```